# Python: setting queue with threading, how to?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a `fetcher.py` that reads URLs from `urls.txt` file and do some work with help of multithreading. When URLs are read from a txt file, a queue is formed, which is then used by threads. Since the file with URLs can be very large, I need to limit the queue. When I specify maxsize - the script is stuck after the queue is formed. If I don't specify maxsize - everything works fine. How to implement and feed this queue with multithreading properly? I have read about "dead pills" for threads but how to use it in my case?
**fetcher.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue


class UrlConverter:
    def load(self, filename: str):
        urls_file_path = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path(filename))
        # queue = Queue() # works fine
        queue = Queue(maxsize=10) # stuck
        with open(urls_file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
            for line in txt_file:
                line = line.strip()
                queue.put(line)
        return queue


class Fetcher:
    def execute(self, url: str):
        try:
            print(f"{url}: OK\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error ", url, ":", str(e))


class FetcherThreads:
    def __init__(self, n: int):
        self.n = n

    def execute(self, queue):
        threads = []
        while not queue.empty():
            while len(threads) < self.n:
                fetcher = Fetcher()
                t = Thread(target=fetcher.execute, args=(queue.get(),))
                t.start()
                threads.append(t)
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
            threads = []


def main():
    url_converter = UrlConverter()
    fetcher_threads = FetcherThreads(10)

    urls_queue = url_converter.load('urls.txt')
    fetcher_threads.execute(urls_queue)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**urls.txt**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea-level_rise
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoia_National_Park
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serengeti
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Nevada_(Utah)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran_Desert
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steppe
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(freshwater)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subarctic_tundra
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Alps
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiga
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatra_Mountains
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperate_rainforest
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_rainforest
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tundra
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ural_Mountains
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetland
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildlife_conservation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_marsh
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savanna
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_Mountains
```

Comment: multithreading Pool will help you

Comment: You do not need a queue for this. Take a look at concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor and its *map* functionality. If you really want to use a queue then you should arrange for the threads to read the queue rather than reading the queue in some kind if "driver" code and then starting a thread. That's woefully inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can get rid of Queue and use `multiprocessing.Pool` instead:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

import requests


def process(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return url, resp.status_code


def get_urls(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f_in:
        for url in map(str.strip, f_in):
            if url == "":
                continue
            yield url


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=10) as pool:
        for url, status_code in pool.imap_unordered(process, get_urls("urls.txt")):
            print(url, status_code)
```

Prints:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran_Desert 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steppe 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Alps 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serengeti 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoia_National_Park 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiga 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea-level_rise 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatra_Mountains 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperate_rainforest 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_rainforest 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tundra 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ural_Mountains 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildlife_conservation 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetland 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Nevada_(Utah) 404
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savanna 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_marsh 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_Mountains 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subarctic_tundra 404
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(freshwater) 404
```

---

EDIT: Example using `ThreadPool`:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

import requests


def process(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return url, resp.status_code


def get_urls(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f_in:
        for url in map(str.strip, f_in):
            if url == "":
                continue
            yield url


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ThreadPool(processes=10) as pool:
        for url, status_code in pool.imap_unordered(process, get_urls("urls.txt")):
            print(url, status_code)
```

Comment: I would suggest that multiprocessing.Pool might be inappropriate in this case on the grounds that that introduces multiprocessing rather than multithreading. If the processing of the URLs involves accessing them (e.g., *requests*) then multithreading might be a better, more efficient, approach

Comment: @Codist I've added example using `ThreadPool`